# I need to show an alert box when the user does not input any number

Tags: javascript, alert

I don't know what I am doing wrong regarding the MaxN function. The max number is showing up correctly. However, when I have to show an alert message in case a user does not input any numbers it shows in the alert "NaN" instead of the required message.
Here is my code:

JS FILE:

```
function getFirstNumber()
{
    var value1 = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
    var fn = parseInt(value1);

    return fn;
}

function getSecondNumber()
{
    var value2 = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
    var sn = parseInt(value2);

    return sn;
}

function getThirdNumber()
{
    var value3 = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;
    var tn = parseInt(value3);

    return tn;
}

function MaxN()
{
    var fn = getFirstNumber();
    var sn = getSecondNumber();
    var tn = getThirdNumber();


    if (fn == "" && sn == "" && tn =="") {
        alert('Please input at least one number');
    } else if (fn >= sn && fn >= tn){
        alert(fn);
    } else if (sn >= fn && sn >= tn){
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert(tn);
    }
}
```

HTML FILE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javafile_exercise.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <span>First number: </span><input type="text" id="fnumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Second number: </span><input type="text" id="snumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Third number: </span><input type="text" id="tnumber" />
    </div>

    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MaxN()">Max Number</button>
    </br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In MaxN add debugger; - you will see that your first logic prefers || over &&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Version 1

You are showing the message only if

`fn == "" and sn == "" and tn ==""`

That means all of the three text fields has to be empty. Using OR statement, should fix your problem.

Than your message should appear, if one of the text field is empty.

At the moment you are calling the function, even if on is empty and so its value i NaN.

Edit fix:

```
if ((fn == "") || (sn == "") || (tn =="")) 
{
  alert('One of the text field is empty');
}
```

### Version 2

Another way to approach this, is returning 0 when the text field is empty. With this way you will always have a number, even if the text field is empty.

```
var value1 = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;

if (value1 == null)
{
  return 0;
}
else
{
  var fn = parseInt(value1);

  return fn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you change your logic, your input values are **not numbers** when nothing is written inside, so you should use `isNaN`.

```js
function getFirstNumber()
{
    var value1 = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
    var fn = parseInt(value1);

    return fn;
}

function getSecondNumber()
{
    var value2 = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
    var sn = parseInt(value2);

    return sn;
}

function getThirdNumber()
{
    var value3 = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;
    var tn = parseInt(value3);

    return tn;
}

function MaxN()
{
    var fn = getFirstNumber();
    var sn = getSecondNumber();
    var tn = getThirdNumber();


    if (isNaN(fn) && isNaN(sn) && isNaN(tn)) {
        alert('Please input at least one number');
    } else if (fn >= sn && fn >= tn){
        alert(fn);
    } else if (sn >= fn && sn >= tn){
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert(tn);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>First number: </span><input type="text" id="fnumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Second number: </span><input type="text" id="snumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Third number: </span><input type="text" id="tnumber" />
    </div>

    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MaxN()">Max Number</button>
    </br>
```

**EDIT** using a different kind of logic by turning `NaN` to 0 at the beginning of the function

```js
function getFirstNumber()
{
    var value1 = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
    var fn = parseInt(value1);

    return fn;
}

function getSecondNumber()
{
    var value2 = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
    var sn = parseInt(value2);

    return sn;
}

function getThirdNumber()
{
    var value3 = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;
    var tn = parseInt(value3);

    return tn;
}

function MaxN()
{
    var fn = isNaN(getFirstNumber()) ? 0 : getFirstNumber() ;
    var sn = isNaN(getSecondNumber()) ? 0 : getSecondNumber() ;
    var tn = isNaN(getThirdNumber()) ? 0 : getThirdNumber() ;


    if (fn == 0 && sn == 0 && tn == 0) {
        alert('Please input at least one number');
    } else if (fn >= sn && fn >= tn){
        alert(fn);
    } else if (sn >= fn && sn >= tn){
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert(tn);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>First number: </span><input type="text" id="fnumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Second number: </span><input type="text" id="snumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Third number: </span><input type="text" id="tnumber" />
    </div>

    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MaxN()">Max Number</button>
    </br>
```

**Last but not least.
What you should do is.**

- use HTML input type `number` e.g. `<input type="number" min="0"
  max="1000" step="1" />`
- use [JavaScript Validation API](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp) (methods `checkValidity()`, `setCustomValidity()`)
- do read carefully the different types of results that can occur during validation

  - **customError**   Set to true, if a custom validity message is set.
  - **patternMismatch**   Set to true, if an element's value does not match its    pattern attribute.
  - **rangeOverflow** Set to true, if an element's value    is greater than its max attribute.
  - **rangeUnderflow**    Set to true, if an    element's value is less than its min attribute.
  - **stepMismatch**  Set to    true, if an element's value is invalid per its step attribute.
  - **tooLong**   Set to true, if an element's value exceeds its maxLength    attribute.
  - **typeMismatch**  Set to true, if an element's value is invalid    per its type attribute.
  - **valueMissing**  Set to true, if an element (with    a required attribute) has no value.
  - **valid** Set to true, if an    element's value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this??

```js
function getFirstNumber()
{
    var value1 = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
    var fn = parseInt(value1);

    return fn;
}

function getSecondNumber()
{
    var value2 = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
    var sn = parseInt(value2);

    return sn;
}

function getThirdNumber()
{
    var value3 = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;
    var tn = parseInt(value3);

    return tn;
}

function MaxN()
{
    var fn = getFirstNumber();
    var sn = getSecondNumber();
    var tn = getThirdNumber();

  if(!isNaN(fn)&&!isNaN(sn)&&!isNaN(tn)){
    if (fn == "" && sn == "" && tn =="") {
        alert('Please input at least one number');
    } else if (fn >= sn && fn >= tn){
        alert(fn);
    } else if (sn >= fn && sn >= tn){
        alert(sn);
    } else {
        alert(tn);
    }
    }
  else 
    alert("Please Enter Numbers Only!!");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javafile_exercise.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <span>First number: </span><input type="text" id="fnumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Second number: </span><input type="text" id="snumber" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <span>Third number: </span><input type="text" id="tnumber" />
    </div>

    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="MaxN()">Max Number</button>
    </br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ...

```
            function getNumber(id, number, ERRMessage) {
                var result = false;
                var elm = document.getElementById(id);
                try {
                    var number = parseInt(value2);
                    var result = true;
                } catch (ex) {
                    ERRMessage = ex.message;
                }
                return result;
            }


            function MaxN(s) {

                //create id array 
                var ids = s.split(" ");
                //init result array
                var numbers = []
                //get the numbers from the form 
                for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    if (getNumber(ids[i], number,ERR)) {
                        numbers.push(number)
                    } else { 
                        console.log(ERR);
                    }
                }
                // do we have 3 numbers at least
                if (numbers.length < 3) { // maybee not
                    alert(tn);
                    return;

                } else {// we have 3 numbers

                    alert("Yippiee"); // get exited
                    console.log(numbers)

                    // get the maximum of the numbers
                    var max = numberts[0];
                    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                        if (numbers[i] > max) {
                            max = numbers[i];
                        }
                    }
                    alert("MAXIMUM is" + max) // show result

                }

            }
```

robust, reusable and flexible just shovel the ids of the input fields in the function. It will also show the maximum of the 3 numbers which was missing i guess.
example call :

```
       var s = "fnumber snumber tnumber";
       MaxN(s);
```